# ElasticSearch Not returning proper boosted results

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to run a complex query that ranks results based on how many words match weighted keyword fields. The problem is that it's not working and results that match more keywords are getting lower scores than results matching less. Anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my query:

```json
    {
    "from": 0,
    "min_score": 5.0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "whse": {
                            "query": "9999"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "partClass": {
                                        "query": "Plumbing"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "partClass": {
                                        "query": "Miscellaneous"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "isDiscontinued": {
                            "value": false
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "should": [
                {
                    "prefix": {
                        "partNo": {
                            "boost": 20.0,
                            "case_insensitive": true,
                            "value": "wolverine brass faucets"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "prefix": {
                        "partNo.keyword": {
                            "boost": 20.0,
                            "case_insensitive": true,
                            "value": "wolverine brass faucets"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "prefix": {
                        "oEM": {
                            "boost": 15.0,
                            "case_insensitive": true,
                            "value": "wolverine brass faucets"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "prefix": {
                        "oEM.keyword": {
                            "boost": 15.0,
                            "case_insensitive": true,
                            "value": "wolverine brass faucets"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "keyword1": {
                            "boost": 15.0,
                            "query": "wolverine brass faucets"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "keyword2": {
                            "boost": 14.0,
                            "query": "wolverine brass faucets"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "keyword3": {
                            "boost": 13.0,
                            "query": "wolverine brass faucets"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "keyword4": {
                            "boost": 20.0,
                            "query": "wolverine brass faucets"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "keyword5": {
                            "boost": 11.0,
                            "query": "wolverine brass faucets"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "keyword6": {
                            "boost": 10.0,
                            "query": "wolverine brass faucets"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "keyword7": {
                            "boost": 9.0,
                            "query": "wolverine brass faucets"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "keyword8": {
                            "boost": 8.0,
                            "query": "wolverine brass faucets"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "keyword9": {
                            "boost": 7.0,
                            "query": "wolverine brass faucets"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "keyword10": {
                            "boost": 6.0,
                            "query": "wolverine brass faucets"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "keyword11": {
                            "boost": 5.0,
                            "query": "wolverine brass faucets"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "keyword12": {
                            "boost": 4.0,
                            "query": "wolverine brass faucets"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "description": {
                            "query": "wolverine brass faucets"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size": 1000
    }
```

And here's my mappings:

```json
    {
    "partinfo_20231113_172838": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "category": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "description": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "filterValue": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "isDiscontinued": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "keyword1": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "customAnalyzerSynonym"
                },
                "keyword10": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "customAnalyzerSynonym"
                },
                "keyword11": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "customAnalyzerSynonym"
                },
                "keyword12": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "customAnalyzerSynonym"
                },
                "keyword2": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "customAnalyzerSynonym"
                },
                "keyword3": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "customAnalyzerSynonym"
                },
                "keyword4": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "customAnalyzerSynonym"
                },
                "keyword5": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "customAnalyzerSynonym"
                },
                "keyword6": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "customAnalyzerSynonym"
                },
                "keyword7": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "customAnalyzerSynonym"
                },
                "keyword8": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "customAnalyzerSynonym"
                },
                "keyword9": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "customAnalyzerSynonym"
                },
                "keywords": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "make": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "oEM": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "keyword",
                    "index_prefixes": {
                        "min_chars": 3,
                        "max_chars": 15
                    }
                },
                "partClass": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "partNo": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "keyword",
                    "index_prefixes": {
                        "min_chars": 3,
                        "max_chars": 15
                    }
                },
                "restrictionCodes": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "salesYTD": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "webURL": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "whse": {
                    "type": "short"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Adding sample results. Note the higher scoring docs that only have two of the 3 keywords in the test query, despite lesser scoring results having the third in a BOOSTED field.

```json
        {
      "took" : 34,
      "timed_out" : false,
      "_shards" : {
        "total" : 1,
        "successful" : 1,
        "skipped" : 0,
        "failed" : 0
      },
      "hits" : {
        "total" : {
          "value" : 602,
          "relation" : "eq"
        },
        "max_score" : 13.688185,
        "hits" : [
          {
            "_index" : "partinfo_20231113_172838",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "T2MTy4sB8M5V6A6viSpT",
            "_score" : 13.688185,
            "_source" : {
              "make" : "PPG",
              "partNo" : "50042",
              "oEM" : "50042",
              "description" : "Stock-EZ Repair Kit for Wolverine Brass Faucets",
              "whse" : 9999,
              "category" : "Stock-EZ Kit",
              "keyword1" : "Wolverine Brass",
              "keyword2" : "Stock-EZ Kits",
              "keyword3" : "Plumbing Kits",
              "keywords" : [
                "Wolverine Brass",
                "Faucet Repair & Rebuild Kits"
              ],
              "filterValue" : [
                " Wolverine Brass ",
                " Plastic ",
                " 59 ",
                " Boxed ",
                " US ",
                " Most popular Wolverine Brass faucets  ",
                " Faucet Repair Kits ",
                " California Proposition 65 Warning, This product can expose you to chemicals including lead, which is known to the State of California to cause cancer and birth defects or other reproductive harm. For more information go to www.P65Warnings.ca.gov"
              ],
              "salesYTD" : 0,
              "isDiscontinued" : false,
              "partClass" : "Plumbing"
            }
          },
          {
            "_index" : "partinfo_20231113_172838",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "UnIby4sB8M5V6A6vflpk",
            "_score" : 13.100534,
            "_source" : {
              "make" : "PPG",
              "partNo" : "85077",
              "description" : "Wolverine Brass Large Label",
              "whse" : 9999,
              "keyword1" : "PlumbMaster",
              "salesYTD" : 0,
              "isDiscontinued" : false,
              "partClass" : "Plumbing"
            }
          },
          {
            "_index" : "partinfo_20231113_172838",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "4I4qy4sB8M5V6A6voF0k",
            "_score" : 13.100534,
            "_source" : {
              "make" : "PPG",
              "partNo" : "PRM000021",
              "description" : "Wolverine Brass Baseball Hat",
              "whse" : 9999,
              "keyword1" : "Wolverine Brass",
              "salesYTD" : 0,
              "isDiscontinued" : false,
              "partClass" : "Plumbing"
            }
          },
          {
            "_index" : "partinfo_20231113_172838",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "91cNy4sB8M5V6A6vF3Hy",
            "_score" : 12.730507,
            "_source" : {
              "make" : "PPG",
              "partNo" : "2593201",
              "oEM" : "2593201",
              "description" : "Wolverine Brass 2593201 Escutcheon, Polished Brass",
              "whse" : 9999,
              "category" : "Escutcheon & Accessories",
              "keyword1" : "Wolverine Brass",
              "keyword2" : "Escutcheons & Accessories",
              "keyword3" : "Tub & Showers",
              "keyword4" : "Faucets",
              "keywords" : [
                "Wolverine Brass",
                "Escutcheons & Accessories"
              ],
              "filterValue" : [
                " Wolverine Brass ",
                " Brass ",
                " Polished Brass ",
                " US ",
                " Shower Valve Trim ",
                " California Proposition 65 Warning, This product can expose you to chemicals including lead, which is known to the State of California to cause cancer and birth defects or other reproductive harm. For more information go to www.P65Warnings.ca.gov"
              ],
              "salesYTD" : 0,
              "isDiscontinued" : false,
              "partClass" : "Plumbing"
            }
          },
          {
            "_index" : "partinfo_20231113_172838",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "bXMcy4sB8M5V6A6vPuoW",
            "_score" : 12.730507,
            "_source" : {
              "make" : "PPG",
              "partNo" : "93781",
              "oEM" : "93781",
              "description" : "Wolverine Brass 93781 Brass Adapter, Chrome",
              "whse" : 9999,
              "category" : "Laboratory Accessories",
              "keyword1" : "Wolverine Brass",
              "keyword2" : "Laboratory Accessories",
              "keyword3" : "General Maintenance",
              "keywords" : [
                "Wolverine Brass",
                "Adapters"
              ],
              "filterValue" : [
                " Wolverine Brass ",
                " Chrome ",
                " 3/8 Inch NPT Female Base ",
                " Brass ",
                " US ",
                " Adapaters 1 ",
                " California Proposition 65 Warning, This product can expose you to chemicals including lead, which is known to the State of California to cause cancer and birth defects or other reproductive harm. For more information go to www.P65Warnings.ca.gov"
              ],
              "salesYTD" : 0,
              "isDiscontinued" : false,
              "partClass" : "Plumbing"
            }
          },
          {
            "_index" : "partinfo_20231113_172838",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "sEgFy4sB8M5V6A6vdKa8",
            "_score" : 12.029424,
            "_source" : {
              "make" : "PPG",
              "partNo" : "00589728C",
              "oEM" : "00589728C",
              "description" : "Wolverine Brass 00589728C Cold Side Stem for Finale Rough Brass Laundry Faucets, Rough Brass",
              "whse" : 9999,
              "category" : "Cartridge & Stem",
              "keyword1" : "Wolverine Brass",
              "keyword2" : "Cartridges & Stems",
              "keyword3" : "Faucet Repair Parts",
              "keyword4" : "Faucets",
              "keywords" : [
                "Wolverine Brass",
                "Cartridges & Stems"
              ],
              "filterValue" : [
                " Wolverine Brass ",
                " Brass ",
                " Finale ",
                " US ",
                " Finale™ Rough Brass Laundry Faucets  ",
                " Cartridges & Stems ",
                " California Proposition 65 Warning, This product can expose you to chemicals including lead, which is known to the State of California to cause cancer and birth defects or other reproductive harm. For more information go to www.P65Warnings.ca.gov"
              ],
              "salesYTD" : 0,
              "isDiscontinued" : false,
              "partClass" : "Plumbing"
            }
          },
          {
            "_index" : "partinfo_20231113_172838",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "s0gFy4sB8M5V6A6vdKa8",
            "_score" : 12.029424,
            "_source" : {
              "make" : "PPG",
              "partNo" : "00589729C",
              "oEM" : "00589729C",
              "description" : "Wolverine Brass 00589729C Hot Side Stem for Finale Rough Brass Laundry Faucets, Rough Brass",
              "whse" : 9999,
              "category" : "Cartridge & Stem",
              "keyword1" : "Wolverine Brass",
              "keyword2" : "Cartridges & Stems",
              "keyword3" : "Faucet Repair Parts",
              "keyword4" : "Faucets",
              "keywords" : [
                "Wolverine Brass",
                "Cartridges & Stems"
              ],
              "filterValue" : [
                " Wolverine Brass ",
                " Brass ",
                " Finale ",
                " US ",
                " Finale™ Rough Brass Laundry Faucets  ",
                " Cartridges & Stems ",
                " California Proposition 65 Warning, This product can expose you to chemicals including lead, which is known to the State of California to cause cancer and birth defects or other reproductive harm. For more information go to www.P65Warnings.ca.gov"
              ],
              "salesYTD" : 0,
              "isDiscontinued" : false,
              "partClass" : "Plumbing"
            }
          },
          {
            "_index" : "partinfo_20231113_172838",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "mGQUy4sB8M5V6A6vFmDD",
            "_score" : 12.029424,
            "_source" : {
              "make" : "PPG",
              "partNo" : "52650W",
              "oEM" : "52650W",
              "description" : "Wolverine Brass 52650W Brass Washer Stem Packing & Washer for Finale Rough Brass Laundry Faucets",
              "whse" : 9999,
              "category" : "Gasket, O-Ring & Washer",
              "keyword1" : "Wolverine Brass",
              "keyword2" : "Gaskets, O-Rings & Washers",
              "keyword3" : "Faucet Repair Parts",
              "keyword4" : "Faucets",
              "keywords" : [
                "Wolverine Brass",
                "Faucet Repair Parts"
              ],
              "filterValue" : [
                " Wolverine Brass ",
                " Brass (Washer) ",
                " Finale ",
                " US ",
                " Finale Rough Brass Laundry Faucets  ",
                " Faucet Repair parts ",
                " California Proposition 65 Warning, This product can expose you to chemicals including lead, which is known to the State of California to cause cancer and birth defects or other reproductive harm. For more information go to www.P65Warnings.ca.gov"
              ],
              "salesYTD" : 0,
              "isDiscontinued" : false,
              "partClass" : "Plumbing"
            }
          },
          {
            "_index" : "partinfo_20231113_172838",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "vmMTy4sB8M5V6A6v3-aX",
            "_score" : 11.709076,
            "_source" : {
              "make" : "PPG",
              "partNo" : "51102",
              "oEM" : "51102",
              "description" : "Wolverine Brass 51102 Stem Packing for 3/8 Stem Faucets",
              "whse" : 9999,
              "category" : "Gasket, O-Ring & Washer",
              "keyword1" : "Wolverine Brass",
              "keyword2" : "Gaskets, O-Rings & Washers",
              "keyword3" : "Faucet Repair Parts",
              "keyword4" : "Faucets",
              "keywords" : [
                "Wolverine Brass",
                "Faucet Repair Parts"
              ],
              "filterValue" : [
                " Wolverine Brass ",
                " US ",
                " 3/8 Inch Stem Faucets  ",
                " Faucet Repair parts ",
                " California Proposition 65 Warning, This product can expose you to chemicals including lead, which is known to the State of California to cause cancer and birth defects or other reproductive harm. For more information go to www.P65Warnings.ca.gov"
              ],
              "salesYTD" : 0,
              "isDiscontinued" : false,
              "partClass" : "Plumbing"
            }
          },
          {
            "_index" : "partinfo_20231113_172838",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "6WMTy4sB8M5V6A6v3-aX",
            "_score" : 11.709076,
            "_source" : {
              "make" : "PPG",
              "partNo" : "51103W",
              "oEM" : "51103W",
              "description" : "Wolverine Brass 51103W Stem Packing for 13/32 Stem Faucets",
              "whse" : 9999,
              "category" : "Gasket, O-Ring & Washer",
              "keyword1" : "Wolverine Brass",
              "keyword2" : "Gaskets, O-Rings & Washers",
              "keyword3" : "Faucet Repair Parts",
              "keyword4" : "Faucets",
              "keywords" : [
                "Faucet Repair Parts",
                "Wolverine Brass"
              ],
              "filterValue" : [
                " Wolverine Brass ",
                " US ",
                " 13/32 Inch Stem Faucets  ",
                " No ",
                " Faucet Repair parts ",
                " California Proposition 65 Warning, This product can expose you to chemicals including lead, which is known to the State of California to cause cancer and birth defects or other reproductive harm. For more information go to www.P65Warnings.ca.gov"
              ],
              "salesYTD" : 0,
              "isDiscontinued" : false,
              "partClass" : "Plumbing"
            }
          },
          {
            "_index" : "partinfo_20231113_172838",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "J2cVy4sB8M5V6A6vQRiC",
            "_score" : 11.709076,
            "_source" : {
              "make" : "PPG",
              "partNo" : "53460W",
              "oEM" : "53460W",
              "description" : "Wolverine Brass 53460W Coupling Adapter for Chicago Faucets, 8 Center",
              "whse" : 9999,
              "category" : "Aerator & Adapter",
              "keyword1" : "Wolverine Brass",
              "keyword2" : "Aerators & Adapters",
              "keyword3" : "Faucet Repair Parts",
              "keyword4" : "Faucets",
              "keywords" : [
                "Wolverine Brass",
                "Faucet Repair Parts"
              ],
              "filterValue" : [
                " Wolverine Brass ",
                " US ",
                " 8 Inch Centers Chicago Faucets  ",
                " Faucet Repair parts ",
                " California Proposition 65 Warning, This product can expose you to chemicals including lead, which is known to the State of California to cause cancer and birth defects or other reproductive harm. For more information go to www.P65Warnings.ca.gov"
              ],
              "salesYTD" : 0,
              "isDiscontinued" : false,
              "partClass" : "Plumbing"
            }
          },
          {
            "_index" : "partinfo_20231113_172838",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "lWcVy4sB8M5V6A6vQRiC",
            "_score" : 11.709076,
            "_source" : {
              "make" : "PPG",
              "partNo" : "53462W",
              "oEM" : "53462W",
              "description" : "Wolverine Brass 53462W Coupling Adapter for Fisher Faucets, 8 Center",
              "whse" : 9999,
              "category" : "Aerator & Adapter",
              "keyword1" : "Wolverine Brass",
              "keyword2" : "Aerators & Adapters",
              "keyword3" : "Faucet Repair Parts",
              "keyword4" : "Faucets",
              "keywords" : [
                "Wolverine Brass",
                "Faucet Repair Parts"
              ],
              "filterValue" : [
                " Wolverine Brass ",
                " US ",
                " 8 Inch Centers Fisher Faucets  ",
                " Faucet Repair parts ",
                " California Proposition 65 Warning, This product can expose you to chemicals including lead, which is known to the State of California to cause cancer and birth defects or other reproductive harm. For more information go to www.P65Warnings.ca.gov"
              ],
              "salesYTD" : 0,
              "isDiscontinued" : false,
              "partClass" : "Plumbing"
            }
          },
          {
            "_index" : "partinfo_20231113_172838",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "UGcVy4sB8M5V6A6voNJW",
            "_score" : 11.709076,
            "_source" : {
              "make" : "PPG",
              "partNo" : "55729W",
              "oEM" : "55729W",
              "description" : "Wolverine Brass 55729W Cartridge Puller for 2 Handle WB Faucets",
              "whse" : 9999,
              "category" : "Cartridge & Handle Puller",
              "keyword1" : "Wolverine Brass",
              "keyword2" : "Cartridge & Handle Pullers",
              "keyword3" : "Plumbing Tools",
              "keyword4" : "Tools",
              "keywords" : [
                "Wolverine Brass",
                "Plumbing Specialty Tools & Accessories"
              ],
              "filterValue" : [
                " Wolverine Brass ",
                " US ",
                " 2 Handle Wolverine Brass Faucets  ",
                " Plumbing Specialty Tools & Accessories ",
                " California Proposition 65 Warning, This product can expose you to chemicals including lead, which is known to the State of California to cause cancer and birth defects or other reproductive harm. For more information go to www.P65Warnings.ca.gov"
              ],
              "salesYTD" : 0,
              "isDiscontinued" : false,
              "partClass" : "Plumbing"
            }
          }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the results you get and why you expect something different?

Comment: Done and amended.

Answer (score 0):

The default `match` query behavior is to match any word in query as docs say:

> **operator**
> (Optional, string) Boolean logic used to interpret text in
> the query value. Valid values are:
>
> **OR (Default)**
> For example, a query value of capital of Hungary is
> interpreted as capital OR of OR Hungary.
> **AND**
> For example, a query
> value of capital of Hungary is interpreted as capital AND of AND
> Hungary.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html

So when you are using

```
"match": {
    "keyword1": {
        "boost": 15.0,
        "query": "wolverine brass faucets"
    }
}
```

it is enough to match any word.

Try to use

```
"match": {
    "keyword1": {
        "boost": 15.0,
        "query": "wolverine brass faucets",
        "operator": "AND"
    }
}
```

Probably you will miss some records now so be ready to complicate your query.